# Bash - How to group data according to first column and retrive last line in a group?

Tags: bash, duplicates, group

In sample of data:

```
aaa  xxx 342
bbb  uuu 727
aaa  yyy 112
bbb  zzz 321 <--
aaa  zzz 288
aaa  zzz 121 <--
```

I would like to group the data by first colum and get the last row from each group.

The result should be like arrows shows above:

```
bbb  zzz 321
aaa  zzz 121
```

How to do this using only bash commands e.g. gawk?
Thanks

Comment: `gawk` is not a Bash command, it's an external utility.

Comment: Please show what you tried and explain why the result was not what you expected.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem:

```
cat file.txt | gawk '{A[$1]=$0}END{for (i in A){print A[i]}}'
```

Solution is from:
https://www.unix.com/shell-programming-and-scripting/223795-awk-how-do-i-get-last-row-group.html